# Redirection with nested commands

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a `$command`, in a instance of a screen, as a different user.
It's run by the equivalent of this command (more detailed at bottom):

```
su $USERNAME -c "screen -dmS $SCREENNAME $COMMAND"
```

and that works great. The problem is I want to redirect the output of `$COMMAND` to some logfile (e.g `$LOGFILE`).

Just adding `> $LOGFILE` to the end seems to read from `screen` instead of `$COMMAND`, so I am stumped as to what I should do. I've tried grouping it with parenthesis and braces, but that caused errors so I probably wasn't doing it correctly.

**So how can I redirect the output of `$COMMAND` to `$LOGFILE`?**

---

The code I am running is "equivalent" to this:

```
execute() {
  su $USERNAME -c "$*"
}
COMMAND="$SOMEDIR/$SOMEPROG $SOMEARGS"
execute screen -dmS $SCREENNAME $COMMAND
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that not all shell parsing features get invoked if you pass the command directly to `screen`. So, the solution is to directly pass the command to a shell, which parses it as expected.

For example, assuming you use bash:
`su $USERNAME -c "screen -dmS $SCREENNAME bash -c \"$COMMAND > $LOGFILE\""`

(The escaped parentheses are so that the command is passed to bash as a whole, otherwise the problem with redirecting `screen`'s output and not the `$COMMAND`'s output would arise again)